# Are there any solid reasons for the "-st", "-nd", "-rd", and "-th" suffixes for numbers?

Tags: word-usage, reading-aloud, etymology, numbers

Is there any reason why we say 1st, 2nd, 3rd and the rest (4, 5,.. 10,..) are all *-th* except the one ending in 1, 2, 3? Why does it change specifically for 1, 2, 3?

Comment: This is a really good example of a question that would actually be better suited to english.SE rather than ell.SE because StoneyB's answer, below, is basically the platonic ideal of an English Language & Usage answer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Historical accident.

- *First* derives from the same root as *fore*, *before*, in the superlative grade—it meant, originally, “fore-est”, that is ‘foremost’.
- *Second* derives from Latin *secundus*, originally a participial form of *sequor* meaning ‘following’

All the others derive from a common Proto-Indo-European ending *-tos*, which in Old English was variously realized, depending on dialect and on phonological context, as *-þe* (þ = {th}, voiced or unvoiced), *-te* or *-de*, before it lost its ending somewhere around the transition from Middle English to Early Modern English and settled on *-th*. The alternate ending *-t* (‘fourt’, ‘fift’, ‘sixt‘, &c) is still to be heard in many dialects.

- *Third*, however, which was regularly *thridde* or *thrydde*, started transposing the *-rid-* to *-ird-* in 10th-century Northumbria, and in the course of the next four centuries this established itself as the preferred pronunciation. Why? Who knows? But the same thing happened to *bird*, which was originally *bryd*.

Comment: Good answer! Has the shift in pronunciation anything to do with the rhotic "R" perhaps, old English pronounced their Rs more than we do today, if memory serves me correctly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Seems likely; /r/ appears to have been particularly frequently involved in [metathesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_(linguistics)). Perhaps an intrusive central vowel which *attracted* the stress?

Comment: Excellent answer. Just to add, since I was curious, it seems the word _second_ was borrowed into Middle English from Old French, partially replacing the Old English _ōþer_, which still survives in modern English as _other_. Had the borrowing not happened, we might today write _2er_ instead of _2nd_.

Comment: But why are eleven, twelve, and thirteen exceptions, taking "th"?

Comment: because they don't end in "first", "second" or "third"